# Sample for for an XSP Object data source that is writable

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm struggling with the Object datasource in an XPage:

```
  <xp:this.data>
    <xe:objectData var="demo" ignoreRequestParams="true"
        readonly="false" scope="view"
        createObject="#{javascript:return new demo.SampleBean();}">
    </xe:objectData>
  </xp:this.data>
```

When I execute `save();` on the XPage in SSJS I get the error:

```
Error saving data source demo
The save method has not been implemented in the data source
```

The class is rather simple:

```
package demo;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SampleBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID  = 1L;
private String name;
private String job;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getJob() {
    return this.job;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setJob(final String job) {
    this.job = job;
}

public void dummyAction() {
        System.out.println("Here shall be logic");
}   

}
```

I tried to add a `public void save();` method to the class, but that doesn't do the trick.
So I'm looking for a sample of an Object datasource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined the `createObject` attribute for the data source, but you haven't specified the `saveObject` attribute... that's what the error message you're getting ("save method has not been implemented") is referring to.

So, for example, if you want your `dummyAction()` method to run when a save is triggered, try this:

```
<xp:this.data>
  <xe:objectData var="demo" ignoreRequestParams="true"
      readonly="false" scope="view"
      createObject="#{javascript:return new demo.SampleBean();}"
      saveObject="#{javascript:return value.dummyAction();}">
  </xe:objectData>
</xp:this.data>
```

When the `saveObject` attribute is specified as a SSJS method binding, the variable `value` is  bound to the data object, and then the method binding is invoked. So you can either pass `value` to some other object to handle the business logic of saving the object, or you can use a syntax of `value.anyMethod()` to keep the business logic of object serialization internal to the object itself.

**NOTE:** whatever logic you do use in this method, you'll want to return a boolean (not `void`), so that a return value of `false` can be treated as a cancellation, just like the standard Domino document data source does.